# Using JSON.stringify on html input

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an html form that contains an input as such..

```
<input type="text" name="colors[]" value="Default" form="createListingForm">
```

I am creating a javascript array and adding all the values to it

```
var data = {user_id: user_id};
var colors = [];
var colorsElement = $('[name="colors[]"]');

if(colorsElement.value != "") {
        for (var i=0; i<colorsElement.length; i++) {
            colors.push(colorsElement[i]);
        }
}
data["colors"] = JSON.stringify(colors);
```

Why when I log `console.log(data["colors"]);` the data to console it outputs `[{}]`

EDIT:
Thank you to Patrick Evans's comment, It was a simple error where I forgot to specify value for `colors.push(colorsElement[i].value)`

Comment: How & when are you invoking the JavaScript you've provided?

Comment: Why are you trying to stringify the whole dom object? If you want the values of the inputs use the `value` property, ie `colorsElement[i].value`

Comment: It is really unclear what you're trying to achieve. Please add more details in your question.